# Pegar conteúdo MultiSelect do Listbox e jogar num Memo na mesma linha

Tags: delphi, lazarus

Preciso jogar o conteúdo com uma ou várias seleções do `TListbox` em um `TMemo`.

Ativei o *MultiSelect* para True,

Estou usando:

```
ListBox.Items[ListBox.ItemIndex]
```

Só que com uma seleção ele lista normal, eu preciso que ele liste caso eu marque suas linhas exiba: selecao1, selecao2

Atualmente só exibe selecao1 independente de quantas eu escolho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve fazer um laço e percorrer toda lista procurando os valores selecionadas, passando 1 a 1.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count -1 do
  begin
    if (ListBox1.Selected[i]) then
    begin
      if (Memo1.Text = '') then
        Memo1.Text := ListBox1.Items[i]
      else
        Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + ', ' + ListBox1.Items[i];
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Aguardo o Feedback.

Comment: Alterei rapido só o fim para RichMemo1.Text :=  RichMemo1.Text + ListBoxOrigem.Items[i] + ','; depois faço um if para não exibir a vírgula no ultimo selecionado, mas deu certo obrigado